# Accessing Pipeline within DoFn

Tags: apache-beam

I'm writing a pipeline to replicate data from one source to another. Info about data sources is stored in db (BQ). How I can use this data  it to build read/write endpoints dynamically?

I tried to pass Pipeline object to my custom DoFn but it can't be serialized. Later I tried to call method getPipeline() on a passed view but it doesn't work as well. -- which is actually expected

I can't know all tables I need to serialize in advance so I have to read all data from db (or any other source).

```java
// builds some random view
PCollectionView<IdWrapper> idView = ...;

// reads tables meta and replicates data per each table
pipeline.apply(getTableMetaEndpont().read())
    .apply(ParDo.of(new MyCustomReplicator(idView)).withSideInputs(idView))

private static class MyCustomReplicator extends DoFn<TableMeta, TableMeta> {
    private final PCollectionView<IdWrapper> idView;

    private DataReplicator(PCollectionView<IdWrapper> idView) {
      this.idView = idView;
    }

    // TableMeta {string: sourceTable, string: destTable}
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element TableMeta tableMeta, ProcessContext ctx) {
      long id = ctx.sideInput(idView).getValue();

      // builds read endpoint which depends on table meta
      // updates entities
      // stores entities using another endpoint
      idView
          .getPipeline()
          .apply(createReadEndpoint(tableMeta).read())
          .apply(ParDo.of(new SomeFunction(tableMeta, id)))
          .apply(createWriteEndpoint(tableMeta).insert());

      ctx.output(tableMetadata);
    }
}
```

I expect it to replicate data specified by TableMeta but I can't use pipeline within DoFn object because it can't be serialized/deserialized.

Is there any way to implement the intended behavior?

Comment: Instead of trying to change the pipeline while it is executing, what about thinking of a flow that is fixed in steps but which instead takes as input the set of tables you want to write to plus the data?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to implement the very similar idea. The restriction is that I can't provide data neither through app params nor through config file. 

My idea is to fetch TableMeta objects using plain big query client (instead of a bq endpoint connector) and to iterate on them in the main scope where I have an access to pipeline